# Prob. 13, Chap. 3 in Baby Rudin: The Cauchy product of two absolutely convergent series converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Here's Prob. 13, Chap. 3 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Prove that the Cauchy product of two absolutely convergent series converges absolutely.

My effort:

Let $\sum a_n$, $\sum b_n$ be two absolutely convergent series of complex numbers, and let $c_n = a_0 b_n + a_1 b_{n-1} + \cdots + a_n b_0 = \sum_{j = 0}^n a_j b_{n-j}$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Let $s = \sum_{n =0}^\infty \left\vert a_n \right\vert$ and $t = \sum_{n =0}^\infty \left\vert b_n \right\vert$. We show that the series $\sum \left\vert c_n \right\vert$ converges; that is, we show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\vert c_n \right\vert < +\infty$.

Now let's take $s_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \left\vert a_k \right\vert$, $t_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \left\vert b_k \right\vert$, and $u_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \left\vert c_k \right\vert$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = s$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n = t$; moreover, the sequences $\left\{ s_n \right\}$ and  $\left\{ t_n \right\}$ are monotonically increasing sequences of real numbers which are bounded above. So $$s = \sup \left\{ \ s_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} \ \ \ \mbox{ and } \ \ \ t = \sup \left\{ \ t_n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}.$$

Thus, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have  $u_n \leq u_{n+1}$ and 
\begin{align}
\left\vert u_n \right\vert &= u_n = \left\vert c_0 \right\vert + \left\vert c_1 \right\vert + \left\vert c_2 \right\vert \cdots + \left\vert c_n \right\vert \\
&\leq \left\vert a_0\right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert + \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_1 \right\vert +  \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert \right) +  \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_2 \right\vert + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_1 \right\vert + \left\vert a_2 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert \right) + \cdots + \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_n \right\vert + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_{n-1} \right\vert + \left\vert a_2 \right\vert \left\vert b_{n-2} \right\vert + \cdots + \left\vert a_n \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert  \right) \\
&= \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \left\vert b_k \right\vert \right) + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left\vert b_k \right\vert \right) +  \left\vert a_2 \right\vert \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \left\vert b_k \right\vert \right) + \cdots + \left\vert a_{n-1} \right\vert \left( \sum_{k=0}^1 \left\vert b_k \right\vert \right) + \left\vert a_n \right\vert \left( \left\vert b_0 \right\vert \right) \\
&\leq \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \left\vert a_k \right\vert \right) \left( \sum_{k=0}^n \left\vert b_k \right\vert \right) \\
&= s_n t_n \\
&\leq st.
\end{align}
Thus, $\left\{ u_n \right\}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence of real numbers with ic bounded above. Hence this sequence converges.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: It's also true if one series converges conditionally and the other converges absolutely.

Comment: There’s just one very small error: for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $u_n\le u_{n+1}$, not $u_n<u_{n+1}$, since it’s possible that $u_n=u_{n+1}=0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how wonderful it feels to hear from you, my dear sir!! Yes, you're right. I've just editted my post to incorporate the correction you've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\left\{a_n\right\}$, $\left\{b_n\right\}$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, are sequences of complex numbers for which the series $\sum \left\vert a_n \right\vert$, $\sum \left\vert b_n \right\vert$ both converge. 
Let $c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. Then we have to show that the series $\sum \left\vert c_n \right\vert$ converges too.

Let $\alpha_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\vert a_k \right\vert$, let  $\beta_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\vert b_k \right\vert$, and let $\gamma_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\vert c_k \right\vert$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$. Let $\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n$ and $\beta = \lim_{n \to \infty} \beta_n$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both non-negative real numbers. Now we show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \gamma_n$ exists and is $\leq \alpha \beta$.

We note that 
$$ \gamma_0 = \left\vert c_0 \right\vert = \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert = \alpha_0 \beta_0,$$
$$\gamma_1 = \left\vert c_0 \right\vert + \left\vert c_1 \right\vert \leq  \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert + \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_1 \right\vert + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert \right) = \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \beta_1 + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \beta_0 \leq \alpha_1 \beta_1,$$ 
$$
\begin{align*}
  \gamma_2 & = \left\vert c_0 \right\vert + \left\vert c_1 \right\vert + \left\vert c_2 \right\vert   \\
   & \leq  \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert + \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_1 \right\vert + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert \right) + \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_2 \right\vert + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_1 \right\vert + \left\vert a_2 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert \right) \\
   & = \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \beta_2 + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \beta_1 +  \left\vert a_2 \right\vert \beta_0 \\
   & \leq \alpha_2 \beta_2,
\end{align*}
$$

and for $n = 3, 4, 5, \ldots$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \gamma_n & = \left\vert c_0 \right\vert + \left\vert c_1 \right\vert + \cdots + \left\vert c_n \right\vert   \\
   &\leq  \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert + \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_1 \right\vert +  \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert \right) + \cdots + \left( \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \left\vert b_n \right\vert +  \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \left\vert b_{n-1} \right\vert + \cdots +  \left\vert a_n \right\vert \left\vert b_0 \right\vert  \right) \\
   &= \left\vert a_0 \right\vert \beta_n + \left\vert a_1 \right\vert \beta_{n-1} + \cdots + \left\vert a_n \right\vert \beta_0 \\
   &\leq \alpha_n \beta_n.
\end{align*}
Thus we have shown that 
$$ \gamma_n \leq \alpha_n \beta_n$$ 
for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Now as $\left\{ \alpha_n \right\}$, $\left\{ \beta_n \right\}$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, are monotonically increasing sequences of real numbers, so we can conclude that 
$$ \alpha = \sup \left\{ \ \alpha_n \ \colon \ n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \ \right\}, \ \  \beta = \sup \left\{ \ \beta_n \ \colon \ n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \ \right\}.$$ 
In particular, we have $0 \leq \alpha_n \leq \alpha$ and $0 \leq \beta_n \leq \beta$; so we also have $\gamma_n \leq \alpha \beta$,  for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Moreover, the sequence $\left\{ \gamma_n \right\}$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, is a monotonically increasing sequence. Therefore this sequence converges and we also have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \gamma_n \leq \alpha \beta. $$

Have I managed to get the proof right this time? If so, is there any way I can improve the presentation of it? If not, then where have I erred?